# Is there a way to resolve ILog using log4net unity extension for DI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container, log4net

So I'm using this [nugget](https://github.com/unitycontainer/log4net) package to integrate log4net with unity container, it allows me to do the following

```
public class test
{
    private ILog logger;
    public test (ILog logger)
    {
        this.logger =logger;
    }
}
```

But I have some classes that don't have a constructor, my approach of the solution was to call resolve but it failed miserably:

```
public ILog GetLogger()
{
    return DIContainer.Container.Resolve<ILog>();
}
```

So am I missing something, or is there a different way for this?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't add a constructor to these classes?

Comment: @Amy The classes I'm interested in atm are my main startup class, a custom ExceptionHandler and a custom ExceptionLogger so adding a constructor to any of these classes is gonna be a really pain in the ass since when  calling `            config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new UnhandledExceptionLogger());` I will need to pass it here as well

Comment: Declare a property and get logger directly from `LogManager` class: `ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);`.  LogManager class has static methods that are used to request an instance of logger

Comment: @Fabjan I tried the following but the loggers initialized like this didn't get the same configuration as the ones initialized by DI

Comment: @Fabjan pointed out the proper way to do it, I think you would be better configuring log4net with it's native configuration methods in `log4net.Config` based on what your DI resolves since the container you're using is made to inject in the constructor. You can easily reload the configuration when Unity notices a change if you are using hot DI. As long as you use `LogManager` to retrieve the loggers you should be completely fine.

Comment: So if I configure log4net in log4net.config, is there a way to name it so whenever I want to use what @Fabjan talked about I get the same config?

Comment: All the methods in `log4net.config` apply the configurations globally, the parameter passed to LogManager is used to identify the instance of the logger, all of them receive the same configuration. It is the container that is using a different "namespace" for the configuration.